# lua cURL module not found

Tags: curl, lua

I have installed lua curl with luarocks and I got no error messages.  When I attempt to do a simple call it says that the module can't be found.

```
#!/usr/bin/lua


local cURL = require "cURL"

c = cURL.easy{
  url        = "https://status.abc.com/integrations/?endpoint=1359&number=111&server=10.21.30.1",
  post       = true,
  httpheader = {
    "Content-Type: application/json";
  };
  postfields = "{}";
}

lua: sendjson.lua:31: module 'cURL' not found:
        no field package.preload['cURL']
        no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.2/cURL.lua'
        no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.2/cURL/init.lua'
        no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/cURL.lua'
        no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/cURL/init.lua'
        no file '/usr/share/lua/5.2/cURL.lua'
        no file '/usr/share/lua/5.2/cURL/init.lua'
        no file './cURL.lua'
        no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/cURL.so'
        no file '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lua/5.2/cURL.so'
        no file '/usr/lib/lua/5.2/cURL.so'
        no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/loadall.so'
        no file './cURL.so' stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'require'
        sendjson.lua:31: in main chunk
        [C]: in ?
```

Comment: according to http://www.luacurl.luaforge.net/: `require 'luacurl'`

Comment: There 2 modules in the LuaRocks - `luacurl` and `lua-curl`. Your example for `lua-curl` module.

Comment: I have installed both luacurl and lua-curl.  None of them seem to work.

Comment: lua-curl definitely works. May be you install module for different version of Lua. you can try to find `lcurl.so` file in your file system.

Comment: @user2236794 Use the command `luarocks show lua-curl` to see the paths where LuaRocks installed the files for the package `lua-curl`. Then you can compare these paths to the paths in the Lua error message to see why Lua could not find the module `cURL`.